# Cordova iPad application got crashed while opening Date Picker

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, jquery-mobile, datepicker

Am using Cordova 3.7.0 and jQueryMobile 1.4.5 version, for datePicker i am using Native datePicker by following code, App is getting crashed while keypad open and try to select Date

```
<input type="date">
```

Any help is appreciated, this happening in only few iPads

Comment: are you using xcode 6?

Comment: There is nothing to do with XCode

Comment: There is a ver y similar bug with input type file and it has to do with xcode, it will crash on xcode 5 or if you use SDK 7